# Jackson serialize Animal and Cat with 2 different serializers depending on the field type of a Cat instance (polymorphistic)

Tags: json, jackson, jackson2

I have a class animal and a class cat that extends that:

```
class Animal {
  protected String name;
  ...
}
class Cat extends Animal {
  protected int livesLeft;
  ...
}
```

Each one has a separate `JsonSerializer`:

```
module.addSerializer(Cat.class, new CatSerializer());
module.addSerializer(Animal.class, new AnimalSerializer());
```

Now I want to serialize an instance of this class:

```
class Foo {
   Cat catA = new Cat("Felix", 9);
   Animal catB = new Cat("Madonna", 3);
}
```

But when I do that, both fields use the `CatSerializer`, so I get

```
{"catA" : {"name":"Felix", "livesLeft":9},
"catB" : {"name":"Madonna", "livesLeft":3}}
```

Which is something I can't deserialize, because the AnimalDeserializer needs to know the type of animal to be able to construct it.

Ideally it would use AnimalSerializer for the field `Animal catB` and I 'd get:

```
{"catA" : {"name":"Felix", "livesLeft":9},
"catB" : {"animalType":"Cat", "name":"Madonna", "livesLeft":3}}
```

which can be deserialized.

Workaround idea: **Is there any way to determine the field type (not just the instance type) during serialization?** So for field `Animal catB = new Cat("Madonna", 3)` that would return `Animal`, not `Cat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you don't want to annotate fields, you can define a [ContextualSerializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/ContextualSerializer.html) that returns a serializer according to field type. You can then extend that for each `Animal` subtype instead of `JsonSerializer`. E.g. :

```
abstract class ByFieldTypeSerializer<T> extends JsonSerializer<T> implements ContextualSerializer {
    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> createContextual(SerializerProvider prov, BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
        // getType will return the field type i.e. Animal for catB
        // SerializerProvider argument knows about all serializers by type
        return prov.findValueSerializer(property.getType());
    }
}

class CatSerializer extends ByFieldTypeSerializer<Cat> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Cat value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // serialize a Cat
    }
}
```

Then simply plug it in:

```
module.addSerializer(Animal.class, new AnimalSerializer());
// Delegates to AnimalSerializer if the field type is Animal instead of Cat
module.addSerializer(Cat.class, new CatSerializer());
```

Comment: Perfect. Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this solution works for you, or any appropriate tweak around this. What makes the behavior you are expecting is the usage of `forType(Animal.class)`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Cat cat = new Cat();
    cat.livesLeft=3;
    cat.name="mycat";
    System.out.println(objectMapper.writer().writeValueAsString(cat));

    Animal animal = cat;
    System.out.println(objectMapper.writer().forType(Animal.class).writeValueAsString(animal));
}

@Data
static abstract class Animal {
    protected String name;

    public String getAnimalType(){
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties("animalType")
@Data
static class Cat extends Animal {
    protected int livesLeft;
}
```

The output generated is as below:

```
{"name":"mycat","livesLeft":3}
{"name":"mycat","animalType":"Cat"}
```

Comment: I have a complication: Animal and Cat are 3th party classes, I can't modify them directly, only write Serializer/Deserializers for them. But with mixins, this solution might work, thank you.